# Strange Swift Syntax, What's It Doing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) tutorial for In-App-Purchases. Here are a few things I don't get:

- For the table, in the rowAtIndexPath they use a handler, what is that?
- They put all the table code in an extension. I don't know why.
- There's also a weird "buyButtonHandler?(product!)" call on button tap

I'd appreciate any clarification on any of the above points. Below is the table code where they put the table in an extension:

```
extension MasterViewController {
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return products.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCell

    var products = [SKProduct]()  //This is actually declared elsewhere 
    let product = products[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.product = product
    cell.buyButtonHandler = { product in
      RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
    }

    return cell
  }
}
```

And the above code includes the strange that I'm looking for help understanding:

```
cell.buyButtonHandler = { product in
  RageProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
}
```

The table cell has a button and in the cell class this is its code:

```
 func buyButtonTapped (_ sender: AnyObject) {
   buyButtonHandler?(product!)
 }
```

It references the below line. This button code/reference is gibberish to me:

```
var buyButtonHandler: ((_ product: SKProduct) -> ())?
```

I don't get what that buyButtonHandler is doing, it's like 50% parenthesis! Lastly, I'm including the below var declaration, in case it helps for context:

```
var product: SKProduct? {
   didSet {
    guard let product = product else { return }

    textLabel?.text = product.localizedTitle

    if RageProducts.store.isProductPurchased(product.productIdentifier) {
      //Setup
    } else {
      //Alternate setup
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The handler is a closure/block. It's basically an anonymous function that can be called stored and called.

Comment: Try to (1) do some research first (2) ask one question at a time. This stuff is as basic as it gets with Swift. Maybe just take a few deep breaths and learn some Swift before proceeding?

Comment: @matt I've seen you post tons of answers on this forum and I always appreciate your help but, with all due respect, I'm skeptical that putting tables in extensions is "as basic as it gets with Swift". I've read a lot of UITableView tutorials and never seen that. And maybe closure blocks (as the other commenter has just called them) are basic but I don't know... are they? Because the syntax is some of the least intuitive, least readable I've seen in the Swift language and I've been reading/learning everyday for a year without seeing them in a tutorial.

Comment: You're totally entitled to disagree with me, and so can everyone else. But speaking entirely personally, I'd be more sympathetic if I saw evidence of effort and if you weren't throwing the whole plate of spaghetti at the wall. I could answer all your questions personally but the way you posed this sucked all my motivation out of the room. Besides, my free online book covers everything you asked about http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ so why repeat myself?

Comment: @matt Fair enough, I did throw the whole plate of spaghetti at the wall and while I usually research stuff a lot before asking this time I didn't. And I may have asked it the wrong way. I think my lack of research and multiple questions in one post are linked, I asked it all at once because I felt like my whole confusion was all quite likely a design choice that I didn't understand and that it'd make more sense to the reader if presented as a whole. Either way, I'll just start Googling it piece by piece. Again, no disrespect, thanks for all the past help.

Comment: "They put all the table code in an extension. I don't know why." ... In addition to Duncan's observation (so that when working with `UITableViewDataSource` methods, they're all together in a logical group), there's also a Xcode usability consideration. Namely, when you're done working on the `UITableViewDataSource` methods and are working on something else, you can use Xcode's "Code folding" (on Xcode's "Editor" menu) to collapse all of that `UITableViewDataSource` code down to a single set of ellipses, avoiding cluttering your screen with code that you might not currently be concerned about.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the additional info. I actually thought folding had disappeared with the newest Xcode version, good to know it's just hiding. On my other app this new idea of using extensions to clean up my code and make it a bit more modular is going to help a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff you're seeing is fairly standard Swift.

Bullet #1:
It looks like the table view cells hold a closure, which is a block of code that they save and run later. The IBAction for the cell's button just invokes the handler block. (The term block and closure are interchangeable. Objective-C calls them blocks, Swift calls them closures.)

So the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath is installing a closure into the cell. That lets you configure your cells from outside. It's a neat trick.

Bullet #2:
It's considered good form to place the methods that implement a protocol in an extension. That way they're all grouped together and easy to find. It also makes the extension into a nice modular block of code. The extension is probably for the `UITableViewDelegate` and/or `UITableViewDataSource` protocol methods.

Bullet #3: 
Same thing as #1. The cell stores a closure (block of code) in a variable, and when the user taps a button, the button's IBAction invokes the stored closure.

Bullet 1 and Bullet 3 mean that in the table view data source's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can provide a custom block of code for each cell that gets invoked when the cell's button is tapped. The code in the button IBAction invokes the stored closure and passes it the current product.